# Groupby based on time and ID between 2

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe of branches and customer transactions which I want to combine.

dataframe 1:

```
 Branch ID 1 | Branch ID 2
      45949  | 59424
      45932  | 59445
      59444  | 59345
```

dataframe 2:

```
 Transaction ID | customer ID | Branch ID| Date
      1243555   | 12224       |   45949  | 01/12/18
      1243556   | 12224       |   59424  | 02/04/18
      1243557   | 12245       |   59445  | 11/05/19
      1243557   | 12245       |   45932  | 12/04/19
      1243557   | 12243       |   45932  | 10/05/19
      1243557   | 12243       |   59445  | 01/05/20
```

I want to find customers that visted both branches based on the transaction date. In dataframe 1, the first row has a share customer in `customer ID` = 12224 because the transaction date for `Branch ID` = 45949 is before `Branch ID` = 59424. Essentially what I want to do is sort dataframe 2 by `Date` and groupby `customer ID`. Then if there is a match between the `Branch ID` from dataframe 1 then I want to add that customer ID to dataframe 1.

Output dataframe

```
 Branch ID 1 | Branch ID 2| Customer IDs
      45949  | 59424      | 12224
      45932  | 59445      | 12245,12243
      59444  | 59345      | N/A
```

I tried:

```
dataframe2.sort_values(['customer ID','Date']).groupby('customer ID')['Branch ID']
```

I dont know how to combine it with dataframe 1

Comment: "I want to find customers that visted both branches based on the transaction date.". Where is the date in `df1`?

Comment: No `df1` represents there are customers who visited  Branch 1 first and Branch 2 second. I want to find those customers from `df2`. Thats why I want to sort by the date and then join

Answer (score 0):

To sort your dataframe :

```
df2 = df2.sort_values('Date').groupby('customer_id')
```

Then you merge with df1 :

```
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left', left_on='BranchID', right_on='BranchID')
```

Then you could sort your new dataframe

Answer (score 0):

1. Get all the customer IDs who visited each branch
2. Slice your dataframe so that the first date before the second date and the customer visited both branches.

```
df1["Branch 1 Date"] = df1["Branch ID 1"].map(dict(zip(df2["Branch ID"], df2["Date"])))
df1["Branch 2 Date"] = df1["Branch ID 2"].map(dict(zip(df2["Branch ID"], df2["Date"])))

df1["Customer ID 1"] = df1["Branch ID 1"].map(df2.groupby("Branch ID")["customer ID"].apply(list))
df1["Customer ID 2"] = df1["Branch ID 2"].map(df2.groupby("Branch ID")["customer ID"].apply(list))

df1["Customer ID"] = df1.dropna().apply(lambda x: set(x["Customer ID 1"]).intersection(set(x["Customer ID 2"])), axis=1)

output = df1[["Branch ID 1", "Branch ID 2", "Customer ID"]]

>>> output
   Branch ID 1  Branch ID 2     Customer ID
0        45949        59424         {12224}
1        45932        59445  {12243, 12245}
2        59444        59345             NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative might be using SQL:

We import `pandasql`

```
import pandasql as ps
joindf  = ps.sqldf("""SELECT BranchID1,BranchID2, CustomerIDs
                    FROM (select t1.BranchID1,t1.BranchID2, coalesce(t2.customerID,-1) as CustomerIDs from df1 t1
                            LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM df2 ORDER BY Date) t2 ON (t1.BranchID1 = t2.BranchID)
                    UNION ALL
                        select t3.BranchID1,t3.BranchID2, coalesce(t4.customerID,-1) as CustomerIDs from df1 t3
                            LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM df2 ORDER BY Date) t4 ON (t3.BranchID1 = t4.BranchID)
                    )
                    GROUP BY
                        BranchID1,BranchID2, CustomerIDs
                    HAVING
                        SUM(1)=2
                         """)

joindf['CustomerIDs'] = joindf['CustomerIDs'].astype('int64').astype('str')
output_df = joindf.groupby(['BranchID1', 'BranchID2'])['CustomerIDs'].apply(','.join)

Output:
BranchID1  BranchID2
45932      59445        12243,12245
45949      59424              12224
59444      59345                 -1
Name: CustomerIDs, dtype: object
```